# HTML automatically adding padding?

Tags: html, css, padding

My problem with this HTML script is that I'm always get a `padding-bottom` in each `div`. Can anybody see why?

```css
 * {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
 }
 body {
   width="1920px";
   height="1080px";
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="images/header.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/stuecke.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/termine.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/team.jpg">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/wo.jpg">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you removed the margins from body? `body{ margin: 0; }`

Comment: As an observation, your body width and height declarations are invalid; they should be `width: 1920px; height: 1080px;`

Answer (score 3):

`<img>` is an inline element, so it gets spacing from the line-height.

Make them `display: block` to prevent that.

Comment: jsfiddle for your help @vinzenzb: https://jsfiddle.net/joelazevedo/6c61d56r/1/